# Does Camrivox Flexor work in Cloud Console?

Tags: service-cloud-console, cti

I'm working with a Flexor CTI Adapter for Salesforce, it is working in the home screen, but when it is opened in cloud Console I'm not able to receive calls or log the activities, anyone has an idea or if this software is not working with cloud console?

This is the link to the software page:

http://camrivox.com/flexor/docs/knowledge_base/en/index.html#Flexor_Manager